# Proper way to make a fat binary prefer to be 32bit on 64bit OS X 10.6?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, 32bit-64bit, fat-binaries

Suppose I ask the user "do you want to run in 32bit mode or 64bit mode" and they pick 32bit.  How do I register this fact with the operating system?  I've looked at the [arch](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/arch.1.html) command, but I don't want to have to write a script that wraps the binary.  I suspect there is a plist-y way to do this, but I can't find documentation (other than arch).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this `Info.plist` key, [`LSArchitecturePriority`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/releasenotes/Carbon/RN-LaunchServices/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001369-CH1-SW1):

```
<key>LSArchitecturePriority</key>
<array>
    <string>i386</string>
    <string>x86_64</string>
    <string>ppc</string>
    <string>ppc64</string>
</array>
```

Just don't do this by dynamically altering your program's bundle. The user running your program might not have permission to write to it. If you need to do this on a per-user basis, a wrapper script would be a preferred alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for something like [LSArchitecturePriority](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-106825-TPXREF124). [Runtime Configuration Guidelines - Property List Key Reference](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPRuntimeConfig/Articles/PListKeys.html) is the documentation for all the key / values for an `.app` bundles `Info.plist` file.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to do it is by setting the ARCHPREFERENCE environment variable, as described on the arch man page.

Comment: Yes, but then I have to set an environment variable.  Messy.