# x84_64 compatibility with 10.5.8

Tags: macos

I would like to build an app with a universal binary containing: ppc, i386 and x86-64.  The problem I have is that on 10.5.8 it tries to launch the x86-64 version and fails.

Is there some configuration that will make 10.5.8 launch with the i386 code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360336/proper-way-to-make-a-fat-binary-prefer-to-be-32bit-on-64bit-os-x-10-6) that suggests to configure through Info.plist.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a method in the OS to target one version of the binary over another. I do know you can use [`lipo`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/lipo.1.html) to remove the x86_64 version of the binary, which will cause the OS to run the i386 version, but I do not think it is what you want.

All that being said it would be my recommendation to debug the cause of the x86_64 crash, or only build the i386 version of the binary until you are in a place to debug it.

Comment: Found the crash, it was an address size conflict 105 to 10.6 SDK.